# why i am getting error syntax error?

Tags: java, mysql

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate","root","root");
String  query1= "select * from registration where email= ? and password= ? ";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query1);
ps.setString(1,email);
ps.setString(2,password);
ResultSet rs1= ps.executeQuery(query1);
rs1.next();
String s= rs1.getString("type");
out.println(s);
```

i am getting following error-

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your 
  SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
  right syntax to use near '? and password= ?' at line 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ps.executeQuery(query1)
```

must be changed to

```
ps.executeQuery()
```

Otherwise, you're not executing the prepared query with the bound parameters, but the unprepared query, without any parameter bound.

Comment: then how will the query be executed if i would not specify query1 inside ps.executeQuery() like ps.executeQuery(query1)